# loop producing unexpected results

Tags: java, math

I expect the loop to end when X equals 0.

The table should go like this

```
X  | Y
10 | 1
8  | 2
6  | 3
4  | 4
2  | 5
0  | 6
```

But when I run it I get the values x = -8 and y = 10

```
int x = 10;
int y = 1;
while ((y != 10) && ((x / y) >= 0))
{
x -= 2;
y += 1;
}

System.out.println("x: " + x);
System.out.println("y: " + x);
```

With the second statement in the while statement being Greater Than or Equal, it would go to -2 and 7, and that should make the second part of the statement false and the loop would cease to run. But it doesn't.

Comment: Use `do while` loop instead.

Comment: It's a test question. I don't understand why the answer is -8 and 10.

Comment: `System.out.println("y: " + x);` : You print the variable `x` again.

Comment: `-2/7` gets truncated to zero, which makes the second comparison true.

Comment: It's not rounding, it's integer division.  Please google integer division to see that -2/7 will give you zero, -4/8 will give you zero, -6/9 will give you zero, and -8/10 will give you zero.  The loop stops when y==10.

Comment: Thank you Joachim. I was looking at it for forever and I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With the second statement in the while statement being Greater Than or
>   Equal, it would go to -2 and 7, and that should make the second part
>   of the statement false and the loop would cease to run.

`-2 / 7` is equal to zero with integer arithmetic.

Try this out:

```
System.out.println((-2/7));
```

**TIP**: Spend the time right now to learn how to run your code in an [IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and step through it in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple, you want only condition that x is greater than zero AND thats it :)

```
    int x = 10;
    int y = 1;
    while ((y != 10) && (x > 0)) {
        x -= 2;
        y += 1;
    }

    System.out.println("x: " + x);
    System.out.println("y: " + y);
```

Output :

```
x: 0
y: 6
```

PS : You have mistake at code posted here, you are printing variable `x` twice

```
System.out.println("x: " + x);
System.out.println("y: " + x);
```

It should be :

```
System.out.println("x: " + x);
System.out.println("y: " + y);
```

Also note following :

This condition didnt work, because of dividing rules in Java. If you divide two `integers` the result is always `integer` rounded down!

So the `(x / y) >= 0` returns true if `x` is smaller than `y`.

To have working example with this kind of dividing, you have to divide for example double with integer, it should look like this

```
((double) x / y) >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `>=` in `(x / y) >= 0)`. -2/7 yields 0 and it passes the condition.

It get's out of the loop by `(y != 10)` and hence the value of y is 10 and in the meantime value of x has gone to -8.